# If a class inherits from an interface that itself implements IDisposable should that class also implement IDisposable or not?

Tags: c#, .net

If a class inherits from an interface that itself implements IDisposable should that class also implement IDisposable or not?

e.g.

```
internal IMyInterface : IDisposable
{
  Method1();
}

internal ClassA : IMyInterface, IDisposable
{
  public Method1
  {
    ...
  }

  public Dispose()
  {
    ...
  }

}
```

or

```
internal ClassA : IMyInterface
{
  public Method1
  {
    ...
  }

  public Dispose()
  {
    ...
  }

}
```

Any clarification on this matter would be most appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does your derived class actually have anything that requires explicit disposal? If not, don't bother. The base takes care of its own disposal requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfaces are contracts and have no implementation of anything. Therefore a class implementing an interface MUST implement everything what the directly or indirectly inherited interfaces dictate. Your code won't even compile if you don't.

YES you must implement `IDisposable` unless you derive your class from a class that already implements it.  (Note: You do not need to specify the `IDisposable` interface in the inheritance list of your class, but you must implement its members.)

---

#### UPDATE

Note: Visual Studio makes it easy for you to implement an interface. A smart tag will automatically appear below `IMyInterface` as long as you have not implemented it completely. You can choose between explicit and implicit implementation of the interface in the smart tag menu. Usually you would choose **implicit**. Then VS will automatically create the (empty) methods, properties and other members required by the interface, including `Dispose`.

Answer (score 2):

The class will have to implement the `Dispose` method anyway.

if you are asking if you **have to declare that your class implements `IDisposable`** as well? so the answer is no, you don't have to

Answer (score 1):

An interface is a declaration. When an interface inherits another interface - it actually adds some more method declarations to the declarations of the inherited interface.

So in your case - IMyInterface will declare both "Method1()" and "Dispose()" methods. No need to add IDisposable again.

Answer (score 0):

Since `IMyInterface` is `IDisposable`, then `ClassA` does not need to inherit directly from `IDisposable` ...otherwise, yes, `ClassA` must implement `IDisposable` in this example.

Comment: I think you mean `implement`, rather than `inherit` with respect to Interfaces.

Comment: @Olivier explained it a lot better than I. But I think I used the correct terminology. ;)

Comment: Inheritance implements "is a" relationships via inherited code. Interfaces are *implemented* (i.e. nothing is inherited). Inheritance has a very specific meaning.

Answer (score 0):

NO , it is not necessary to implement the Dispose seperately since the Interface won't let it compile Until `Dispose()` is there.